# For an array a and b in Python, what is the code a[b[0:2]] is actually trying to do?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy, slice

Could somebody please help on explaining the meaning of this error message?

There is this part of lines of code that I am trying to understand. So I experimented myself with an easier example.

I have

```
a = array([[0, 1],  
       [2, 3],  
       [4, 5]])
```

and

```
b = [1,3,5,7]
```

I wrote

```
a[b[0:2]]
```

and there is an error comment :

> index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

I understand what does `b[0:2]` means, it means you take the element of `b` with index 0 to index 1, so you get `[1,3]`. But I don't quite understand what does it mean when you pass it to `a`?

I am trying to understand what is the code `a[b[0:2]]` is actually trying to do.

Could somebody please lend a help? Thanks!

Comment: What did you try to do? i.e. assuming a & b as you defined, which output would you like to get?

Comment: Do you understand what `b[0:2]` might mean? The return value of that expression is then passed to `a[...]`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Yaron I am not trying to get any output, I am just experimenting myself and trying to understand the meaning of the code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I understand what b[0:2] means. But I am still trying to understand what does it mean when you pass it to a?

Comment: @user71346: look at this way: `temp = b[0:2]`, then `a[temp]`. Apart from creating a `temp` variable, the result is *exactly the same*.

Comment: @user71346: Did you manage to understand my explanation in my answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1],  [2,3],[4,5]])
>>> a2 = np.array([[0, 1],  [2,3],[4,5],[6,7]])
```

Two arrays:

a - with elements number 0 to 2

a2 - with elements number 0 to 3

```
>>> b[0:2]
[1, 3]
```

b[0:2] - means two elements (#1 and #3)

```
>>> a[b[0:2]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

means - you try to get elements #1 and #3 from a. But you don't have element #3 in a

```
>>> a2[b[0:2]]
array([[2, 3],
       [6, 7]])
>>>
```

means - you try to get elements #1 and #3 from a2. the result is: two elements #1 is [2,3] and #3 is [6,7]

Comment: Yes I understood it now. Thanks very much!

Comment: @user71346 : great :-)